# R - dplyr mutate with function only checks first row

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a list of times and I want to place them into buckets. 
i.e. '9:00 PM' goes into the '7:00 PM - 12:00 AM' bucket

The function is as follows:

```
bucket.start.time <- function(x) {
  if (strptime(x, format = "%I:%M %p") >= strptime("7:00", format = "%R") && 
      strptime(x, format = "%I:%M %p") < strptime("12:00", format = "%R")) {
    timebucket <- "7:00 AM - 11:59 AM"
  }
  if (strptime(x, format = "%I:%M %p") >= strptime("12:00", format = "%R") && 
      strptime(x, format = "%I:%M %p") <= strptime("16:30", format = "%R")) {
    timebucket <- "12:00 PM - 4:30 PM"
  }
  if (strptime(x, format = "%I:%M %p") > strptime("16:30", format = "%R") && 
      strptime(x, format = "%I:%M %p") < strptime("19:00", format = "%R")) {
    timebucket <- "4:31 PM - 6:59 PM"
  }
  if (strptime(x, format = "%I:%M %p") >= strptime("19:00", format = "%R") && 
      strptime(x, format = "%I:%M %p") < strptime("24:00", format = "%R")) {
    timebucket <- "7:00 PM - 12:00 AM"
  }
  return(timebucket)
}
```

I then used mutated to create a second column:

```
mutate(Appointments, Time.Bucket = bucket.start.time(Start.Time))
```

What I found is that since the first row had a Start.Time of '12:30 PM', the function populated the Time.Bucket column exclusively with '12:00 PM - 4:30 PM'. How can I get mutate to apply my function on each row individually, instead of applying it once to the first row and copying the result to the rest?

Comment: I think you need `&` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers, I'm going to try that. I fixed it by creating a loop and having my function output a vector of bucket values. If you're right, then your method is much better than mine!

Comment: Using a `for` loop is definitely not necessary here. Take a look at `?base::logic`. `&` is the *vectorised* logical OR operator, which you need here.

Comment: Your function is not vectorized:

Comment: @MauritsEvers I kind of see what's going on. I can use the vectorized & to apply these if statements on my whole vector of Start Times. But I have four different conditional statements, so I'm a little confused how to  combine four logic vectors into one column. Could I use a logic switch? And do I still need to output a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
bucket.start.time =function(m){
  x=c("7:00 AM","12:00 PM","4:31 PM","7:00 PM","11:59 PM")
  x=strptime(x,format = "%I:%M %p")
  y=c("7:00 AM - 11:59 AM","12:00 PM - 4:30 PM",
      "4:31 PM - 6:59 PM","7:00 PM - 12:00 AM")

  cut(strptime(m,format = "%I:%M %p"),x,y)
}

mutate(Appointments, Time.Bucket = bucket.start.time(Start.Time))
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is very concise, thank you! Out of curiosity, do you see a way it could be done with logical vectors created with &, similar to what others have commented above?

Comment: To avoid forloop, you might use findInterval function.. or a nested ifelse statement... ifelse is vectorized while if ..else. Is not vectorezed. If ..else must take a logical argument of length 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best answer, but I think the most important thing was for me to output a vector. I used a for loop to modify my function:

```
bucket.start.time2 <- function(x) {
  totalbuckets <- vector(mode="character", length=length(x))
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {  
    if (strptime(x[i], format = "%I:%M %p") >= strptime("7:00", format = "%R") && 
        strptime(x[i], format = "%I:%M %p") < strptime("12:00", format = "%R")) {
      timebucket <- "7:00 AM - 11:59 AM"
    }
    if (strptime(x[i], format = "%I:%M %p") >= strptime("12:00", format = "%R") && 
        strptime(x[i], format = "%I:%M %p") <= strptime("16:30", format = "%R")) {
      timebucket <- "12:00 PM - 4:30 PM"
    }
    if (strptime(x[i], format = "%I:%M %p") > strptime("16:30", format = "%R") && 
        strptime(x[i], format = "%I:%M %p") < strptime("19:00", format = "%R")) {
      timebucket <- "4:31 PM - 6:59 PM"
    }
    if (strptime(x[i], format = "%I:%M %p") >= strptime("19:00", format = "%R") && 
        strptime(x[i], format = "%I:%M %p") < strptime("24:00", format = "%R")) {
      timebucket <- "7:00 PM - 12:00 AM"
    }
    totalbuckets[i] <- timebucket
  }
  return(totalbuckets)
}
```

It now works in the following statement:

```
mutate(Appointments, Time.Bucket = bucket.start.time(Start.Time))
```